# How to bind gridview's itemtemplate from other list's item

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I don't know if it is possible or not. But I want to hear out if there is a possibility for the following:
I have a gridview linked to a objectdatasource. This objectdatasource has a list of tickets objects. This ticket object contains properties of multiple id's. Let's take for example computerID. I have another list which the class Computer has properties computerID and ComputerName.
What I want to achieve is when the gridview is loaded to have computername instead of computerID.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvTickets" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="odsTickets" AllowPaging="True">
       <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" SortExpression="ID" Visible="false" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FullID" HeaderText="FullID" SortExpression="FullID"></asp:BoundField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ComputerID">

            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ComputerID") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="StatusID" HeaderText="StatusID" ></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CategoryID" HeaderText="CategoryID"></asp:BoundField>
    </Columns></SelectedRowStyle>
</asp:GridView>
```

odsTickets contains a select statement that retrieves List

```
Class Ticket
{
private int computerID;
public int ComputerID
    {
        get { return computerID; }
        set { computerID = value; }
    }
}
```

I have a list of Computer List in cache that I would like to retrieve that data from.

```
Class Computer
{
private int computerID;
public int ComputerID
    {
        get { return computerID; }
        set { computerID = value; }
    }
private string computerName;
public string ComputerName
    {
        get { return computerID; }
        set { computerID = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: So pass the conputer name along with the list and bind it to a column.

Comment: Also, can you show us the HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ComputerName">

        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# this.ComputerListFromCache.First(x => x.ComputerId == Convert.ToInt32(Eval("ComputerID"))).ComputerName %>'>  </asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

Use linq to get Computer object from your list by Id and get value of ComputerName (it assumes that 'ComputerListFromCache' is accessible from the page that has grid view and that list is not 'private').